# Check if phone is in call (WP7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, phone-call

In windows phone 7 ... Is there is a way to check if the phone is now busy with a call as in android

if yes, what is the name space that serve this?

Comment: If I remember correctly when there is a call the running application is deactivated, so I there is no API to check it because your app won't run when the call is happening.

Comment: @nemesv A background agent could still be running, but there's no API to know if there's an on-going call anyway

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented there is currently no API within the Windows Phone SDK to detect whether a call is in progress.

Tim Askins wrote a fairly [detailed post](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2012/03/14/responding-to-incoming-phone-calls-on-wp7/) on his attempts to get around this but ultimately it just isn't possible.